# jquery selector first child of ul tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a menu structure like this:

```html
 <ul>
    <li><a href="">One</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Two</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub One</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub One One</a>...</li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub One Two</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sub Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Two One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Two Two</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sub Tree</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Tree</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now... How can i select all sub first "ul" tags in class "active" ?

sample, active > "ul" (sub one) > "ul" (sub one one) ... etc.

Comment: do you want all sub UL to be active on hover ?

Comment: plz post the code you have tried so far???

Comment: Kartikeya i don't tried.. Nadeem etc.. but onload page open all sub ul

Comment: sample : http://jsfiddle.net/qe4zkw02/3/ but not dynamic level

Comment: Your question is ` How can i select all sub first "ul"`

Comment: because dynamic level

Answer (score 1):

You can select like this

**JQuery**

`$('ul li.active>ul')`
**OR**
`$('li.active').children('ul')`

**CSS**

`ul li.active ul {}`

Comment: *ReferenceError: ul is not defined*. Your selector needs to be placed within a string.

Comment: only first sub ul tags select

Comment: @HashemQolami thats my bad

Answer (score 1):

`$("li.active").find("ul")` will do the trick. Following is the simple code where you can log all the UL elements inside active li.

```js
var ulArr = $("li.active").find("ul");

console.log("First UL of active li is: " + ulArr[0]);

$.each(ulArr, function(index, element) {
  console.log("Child UL number " + index + " is: " + element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">One</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Two</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub One</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub One One</a>...</li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub One Two</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sub Two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Two One</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Sub Two Two</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Sub Tree</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Tree</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your selector needs to be placed within a string.

Comment: only first ul's select

Comment: The result will give you array of `ul` inside active li, even if it's further inside some elements. So, you've to loop the array

Comment: something like this `var ulArr = $("li.active").find("ul")`. `ulArr.forEach(//Code)`

Comment: Please answer this - Do you want to select first `ul` inside active list or all the `ul`s? I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: first uls @BikasVaibhav

Comment: Any reason for unaccepting the answer? That too this late?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("li.active >ul:first")
```

Comment: @TamerAğaoğlu ,You did not include jquery. working demo http://jsfiddle.net/buhn1j9d/1/

Answer (score 0):

$('.active ul>li>a').first()

```js
$(function() {
  var active = $('.active ul>li>a').first().addClass('red');

});
```

```css
.red {
  color:red !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="">One</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">Two</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub One</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub One One</a>...</li>
          <li><a href="">Sub One Two</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Two</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Two One</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Two Two</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Tree</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Tree</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```